# 'Client not found in Kerberos database' when joining domain with Likewise

Tags: lubuntu, likewise

I have installed Lubuntu and I'm trying to connect it to my works Domain, but I'm getting an error from Likewise -

> LW_ERROR_KRB5KDC_ERR_C_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN - 
>   Client not found it Kerberos database

At first I thought this could be because Linux did not create a computer object in the OU when joining to a domain, so I created on with the name that I was giving the computer and tried again, but I got the same error.

I really have no clue why this is happening, so I wonder if any one can give me some pointers? Thanks.

Here is a screen shot of how I am trying to add the computer, and of the error generated -

[image: likewise-error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here was actually very simple. I had chosen not to enable the default username prefix, and in Windows I have to use 'dd\username' when passing credentials. However, in Lubuntu, I didn't need to do that, and just my username was sufficient. So all sorted.